# How can I locally develop Angular 7 libraries that depend on each other? (npm link issues)

Tags: angular, npm, angular7, angular-library, npm-link

I have two angular library NPM packages:

- **A** has basic components
- **A-BC** has components that build upon the components in **A**, with added features to integrate with **BC** library

Some components in `A-BC` import from `A` like `import { MyThing } from 'A';`

`A-BC`'s package.json is:

```
"peerDependencies": {
   "A": 1.0.0,
   "BC": 4.0.0
},
"devDependencies": {
   "A": 1.0.0,
   "BC": 4.0.0
}
```

My attempted development steps were to:

1. `npm link --only=production` in (the built version of) `A`
2. `npm link --only=production` in (the built version of) `A-BC`
3. In `my-app`, run `npm link A`
4. In `my-app`, run `npm link A-BC`
5. Run `my-app`

Compilation of `my-app` fails when `A-BC` can't find `A` installed anywhere. They are both listed correctly in `node_modules` right next to each other, as symlinked folders. I have tried this with `preserveSymlinks` enabled in `tsconfig.json` and `angular.json`, but that did not help.

`A` could be a direct dependency of `A-BC`, but:

- Both `A` and `A-BC` have a `forRoot()` called that is required for the package to function properly for the app it is installed in. I don't know of a way to pass the `forRoot()` parameters dynamically from the `A-BC` `forRoot()` to the `A` `forRoot()`
- `my-app` needs to use components from `A` AND components from `A-BC`.
- If `A` was a direct dependency, I don't know how I would be able to develop `A-BC` locally--which can involve changing both `A-BC` and occasionally `A`.

Currently my band-aid solution is to:

1. Publish `A` as a beta version
2. Install the beta version in `A-BC` and `my-app`
3. Link `A-BC` to `my-app` via `npm link`
4. Publish a new beta version of `A` if changes need to be made, then install that in `my-app` and `A-BC` again

There may be an alternative workflow around installing `A` via NPM's support for local files, but I'm not sure.

Comment: There is this awesome free ebook from @nrwl: https://connect.nrwl.io/app/books/enterprise-angular-monorepo-patterns. It suggests a very robust architecture based on a monorepo. Each part of the app is an independent library with no need to be uploaded to npm (ever if you desire).

Comment: @jpavel I don't know if this setup change is feasible for right now, but it's possible on a longer timeline. I'm going to dive into angular monorepo patterns and experiment with them to see if we want to restructure. I can definitely see the benefits but it might be too disruptive to some of our related workflows for now.

Comment: Did you resolve this issue?

Comment: @Fasco The projects are now in an nx angular monorepo (https://nx.dev/angular), with imports from the libraries being done directly. This is much simpler, and cuts out the need for npm altogether

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that those two packages that you are talking about were created either with ngCli v6, or you are merging them from already existing ng workspaces, either way let's try to solve your problem.

I will assume that you have ng workspace structure like the following one

```
...
projects >
  A
  B
  host
...
```

Where A is a lib B is a lib which depends on A and host is an application that uses B.

When working/developing ng packages locally in your ng workspace, you should add their aliases to your `root` `tsconfig.json` file like :

```js
{
 ...
"compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "paths": {
      "a": [
        "dist/a"
      ],
      "a/*": [
        "dist/a/*"
      ],
      "b": [
        "dist/b"
      ],
      "b/*": [
        "dist/b/*"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This is done automatically for you in the CLI v7 when generating a library with `ng new lib {yourLibName}` command.

After making sure that you have this configuration I would suggest adding some scripts to your `package.json`, in order to build your libs and serve your development app in more straightforward way (`host` in the case of the example)

```
"build:a": "ng build A --watch=true",
"build:b": "ng build B --watch=true",
"serve:host": "ng serve host"
```

After that, by running the three scripts one after another and importing the appropriate `libModules` from `lib B` in your `Host App` and the appropriate `libModules` from `lib A` inside `Lib B`, you will be able to use the components of `lib B`, which depend on components from `lib A` inside the `Host APP`.

Keep in mind that you must not install the two libs in your workspace, because that will break the imports inside your projects, also those libs should not be part of your workspace `package.json`.

If you had already completed the above steps and your problem is not fixed, please provide us with link to a git repo, or share your `tsconfig.json`, `package.json`, `angular.json` files, so that we can continue with the investigation.

## Answer to sub comment

So if I get your case, you want to be able to develop those `packages`  and also install them in one single ng workspace.

If this is the case, as far as I know, there is no straight forward way to do it, probably you will be able to achieve this behavior (as you suggested in the comment) by tweaking your `tsconfig.json` files.

But in my opinion, if you want to use this `ng packages` inside the same workspace, you don't necessarily need to push them, as at the end of the day they are just another set of `ngModules` that will be "first-class citizens" inside the applications where you reffer them. So when building for production, they will be tree-shaken, minimized-optimized and so on. In this case, you should just extend the deployment script in your `package.json`, in such way, that before you start building the main app, that will depend on those `npm/ng/packages`, you build that packages.

```
"deploy": "ng build A && ng build B && ng build MainApp --production"
```

At the same time, those same `npm/ng/packages` will still be `npm` publishable and you will be able to use them in other workspaces. 
**Keep in mind that they should not be part of the same(the workspace where they are being developed) workspace's `package.json` dependencies.**

Comment: After reading this, I've looked into angular workspaces and put my applications inside the `projects` folder. The development flow works fine for importing the packages via `paths` during development, but now there are issues building for production. It seems like it is just a matter of setting a production `tsconfig` in `angular.json` that doesn't rely on the local paths. Then the live package versions could just be `npm install`ed in applications before building. Does that seem like the right workflow?

Answer (score 0):

What I was trying to do initially had a lot of problems because the scenario was wrong to begin with.

The main two things I learned here were that:

1. **Packages only used in internal angular projects should not be
   published to npm**
2. **If libraries depend on each other, they should import directly from your typescript/angular source**

If you are trying to make the scenario I described work, it will give you an endless headache because it is a fundamentally broken approach.

Now all of the related projects that share these libraries are in a single [nx monorepo](https://nx.dev/). With the libraries being directly imported, everything just works automatically with live reloading, tree shaking, etc, as other answers/comments here suggested. Migrating was not much of a hassle, and the tooling for the monorepo setup is pretty good.

When setting up your monorepo to make this scenario work, the libraries will be imported to each project via tsconfig paths, as below. This makes the old import statements for the npm packages able to stay the same, as your paths can just reference the name of the previous npm package (like A or A-BC in the question above).

Every project also now shares the same package json, and the npm scripts for serving, building, etc have been greatly improved by centralizing these tooling scripts in the monorepo root, instead of having tooling separately in each repo.

The path for `@angular/*` fixed some issues with the libraries conflicting.

**Example paths from /apps/example-project/tsconfig.json**

```
   "paths": {
      "@angular/*": ["../node_modules/@angular/*"],
      "@exampleNPMOrg/A": [
        "../../libs/A/src/index"
      ],
      "@exampleNPMOrg/A-BC": [
        "../../libs/A-BC/src/index"
      ],
    }
```

**Example paths from /tsconfig.json**

```
   "paths": {
      "@exampleNPMOrg/A": [
        "libs/A/src/index"
      ],
      "@exampleNPMOrg/A-BC": [
        "libs/A-BC/src/index"
      ],
    }
```